# Use Airport Express as a WIFI extender on non-Apple?

Tags: wifi, airport

I have a wireless router / modem from my cable provider and I was looking to use my existing Airport Express as a WIFI range extender. Is this possible? I currently have it connected directly with a cat6 cable but I rather use it wirelessly to get extra range.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sadly not possible, you can only extend a network created by another Airport Extreme/Express.